# What happens if one @Transactional annotated method is calling another @Transactional annotated method on the same object instance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I am studying how to Spring handle transaction and I am asking what happens if one `@Transactional` annotated method is calling another `@Transactional` annotated method on the same object instance?

I know that the transactional propagation defaul level is `REQUIRED` so if I have a `method1()` annotated with `@Transactional` of an instance of `MyObject` that call a `method2()` (annotated with `@Transactional`) of the same instance I think that, following the `REQUIRED` level, it is performed on the same transaction created by `method1()`.

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something? I am not sure about what exactly happens if the 2 `@Transactional` methods are called on the same instance.

How it works?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you call `method2()` from `method1()` within the same class, the `@Transactional` annotation of the second method will not have any effect because it is not called through proxy, but directly. Methods are enhanced with transactional behavior only if called through proxy (autowired bean, or some instance injected in any other way).

But generally speaking, if `method1()` and `method2()` were in different classes, and both were annotated with `@Transactional` (so using `REQUIRED` propagation), then they would share the same transaction started in `method1()`.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: I would also like to know why this answer got downvoted. The second paragraph should be rephrased perhaps, as it depends on the propagation level, but since the default propagation is REQUIRED the paragraph stands true.

Comment: Tnx, perfect explaination :-)

Comment: @PredragMaric what if method2() sets propagation to REQUIRES_NEW ?

Comment: @Miguel REQUIRES_NEW will create a second transaction, which can be committed or rolled back independently of the first one.